# Change the position of text of table body except the action buttons in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, razor-pages

This is my table UI, I want that the text in it comes at the left of the column but the buttons present in "Action" column also getting effect, I want that only text will come at the right side of the column

[image: 2]

Here is the css of the table D.

```
.table td {
    font-size: 0.813rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #8d97ad;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:not` selector and the `:last-child` selector to apply a style to all `td` elements except those of last column.

```
.table td:not(:last-child) {
    text-align: right !important;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp